# R: read fwf file with missing final column

Tags: r, parsing, readr, read.fwf

I am attempting to parse a fixed-width .txt files with `readr`'s `read_fwf`. There are ~1.5 million observations and approx. 550 of them are missing the final 25 of 60 variables. This omission leads to the inperfect parsing of the final variable that these observations do have, 'description' in the example below, and leaves the dataframe without these partially filled columns.

For example,

```
df_baseline <- read_fwf(file = file, fwf_widths(fwf_widths, fwf_names), 
                         col_types = col_types, trim_ws = T) %>% 
   mutate_all(na_if, "")
Warning: 1148 parsing failures.
row         col   expected     actual file
300495 description 240 chars  102        '/path/to/my/file/filename.txt'
300495 NA          59 columns 31 columns '/path/to/my/file/filename.txt' 
500245 description 240 chars  56         '/path/to/my/file/filename.txt' 
500245 NA          59 columns 31 columns '/path/to/my/file/filename.txt' 
500333 description 240 chars  33         '/path/to/my/file/filename.txt' 
See problems(...) for more details.
```

`col_types` is a string of 60 `'c'` symbols in a row so that all columns are read-in as character. `fwf_widths` and `fwf_names` are appropriately specifications for the proposed column widths and column titles.

I understand that by having missing values in the final column of the df, I am violating the "fixed-width" nature of the document.

Is there a way that I can 1) Get `read_fwf` to retain these partially filled rows?
2) If not, how can I read in this txt file given that 99% of it can be parsed according to a normal FWF?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data.table::fread()`. It automatically detects fixed width formats and using the option `fill=TRUE` should give you what you want:

```
#abc.txt
#a   b   c   d
#1   2   3   4
#1   2   3   4
#2   3
#1   4   3   2
library(data.table)
fread('abc.txt',fill = T)
#    a b  c  d
# 1: 1 2  3  4
# 2: 1 2  3  4
# 3: 2 3 NA NA
# 4: 1 4  3  2
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful. However, I'm still experiencing a problem with `fread` whereby it incorrectly assumes the number of columns. I get the error: "Stopped early on line 399. Expected 45 fields but found 48" when in fact there are 60 variables. I can't find anywhere in the `fread` docs where I can specify the variable widths, is there a space to plug this in?

Answer (score 0):

The question is ambiguous and therefore difficult to answer directly or precisely, but the fwf file ABCD.txt illustrates three cases the OP might be asking about:

```
# ABCD.txt
# 1ABCD
# 2AB
# 3AB D
# 4ABD
# 5ABCD
#
```

**Rows 1 and 5** have no missing values and can be parsed without issue.

**Rows 2 and 3** (the first truncated after three values; the second with an empty placeholder in the fourth column) can also be parsed without issue by `read_fwf`, although there will be a warning (like that cited by the OP) about the truncation in row 2 (and row 4, which we treat below):

```
widths <- c(1,1,1,1,1)
file <- "ABCD.txt"

abc <- read_fwf(
  file = path,
  fwf_widths(widths),
  col_types = "ccccc"
  )

abc
```

Output:

```
Warning: 3 parsing failures.
row col  expected    actual       file
  2  X4 1 chars   0         'ABCD.txt'
  2  -- 5 columns 4 columns 'ABCD.txt'
  4  X5 1 chars   0         'ABCD.txt'

# A tibble: 5 x 5
  X1    X2    X3    X4    X5   
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 1     A     B     C     D    
2 2     A     B     NA    NA   
3 3     A     B     NA    D    
4 4     A     B     D     NA   
5 5     A     B     C     D
```

Note that `read_fwf` fills the truncated rows with `NA` for the missing values.

`read.fwf` with `fill = TRUE` also works, although it is slower and will not throw any warnings:

```
abc <- read.fwf(
  path,
  widths =  widths,
  colClasses = "character",
  na.strings = c(" ","NA"),
  fill = TRUE
  )

abc
```

Output:

```
  V1 V2 V3   V4   V5
1  1  A  B    C    D
2  2  A  B <NA> <NA>
3  3  A  B <NA>    D
4  4  A  B    D <NA>
5  5  A  B    C    D
```

**Row 4**, however, is not parsed "correctly" with either approach if we know that the value `D` is supposed to be in the fifth column. (There is no way for `read_fwf` or `read.fwf` to know this, though, so strictly speaking, there is no parsing error.)

There are a number of ways to handle this issue, but if the problem is consistent throughout the fwf file (e.g. the final 25 of 60 variables are missing in all such cases, as specified in the question), then one solution is to use `dplyr` to transpose the improperly placed `D` value from the fourth to the fifth column (or from the 35th to the 60th column, in the OP's case):

```
abc <- abc %>%
  mutate(
    V5 = case_when(
      is.na(V5) & !is.na(V4) ~ V4,
      !is.na(V5) ~ V5
      ),
    V4 = case_when(
      V4!=V5 ~ V4
      )
    )

abc
```

Output:

```
  V1 V2 V3   V4   V5
1  1  A  B    C    D
2  2  A  B <NA> <NA>
3  3  A  B <NA>    D
4  4  A  B <NA>    D
5  5  A  B    C    D
```